# Unique Mac address for Secondary IP address?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ping, mac-address, ip-address

Using one Ubuntu machine with one physical NIC, I want to make it seem that there are two or more additional machines on my **real** network, all controlled by this one Ubuntu machine.

For example, I have a 192.168.1.x network.
My Ubuntu machine has an IP of 192.168.1.10 with a mac address of 00:11:22:33:44:55.
I want to make deploy another "machine" with an IP address of 192.168.1.11 and a mac address of 55:44:33:22:11.

Therefore, when I arp-scan the local network from 192.168.1.9, it should display the following.

```
...
192.168.1.10     00:11:22:33:44:55
192.168.1.11     55:44:33:22:11:00
...
```

**Both machines need to respond to ping as well from other real machines on my real network.** The idea is to make it seem to 192.168.1.9 that there .10 and .11 are **two independent machines** on the real network.

Looking for a relatively simple set of commands that would create this "machine", without creating any additional virtual machines or docker containers.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You can create a network namespace with a macvlan. If you only need a response to a ping, you needn't do anything else in that namespace, just give it a macvlan (and maybe assign an address if you don't have a DHCP server on that segment).

Comment: @dirkt Thanks for your response! Can you please provide an example command that I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a system with address 192.168.1.175:

```
# ip addr show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:f0:5d:c9:12:a9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname eno2
    altname enp0s31f6
    inet 192.168.1.175/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 80184sec preferred_lft 80184sec
    inet6 fe80::ed9c:756f:92a:ef21/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

We're going to add a macvlan interface with the address 192.168.1.190 and demonstrate that it has a different MAC address.

Create a network namespace:

```
ip netns add ns0
```

Create a macvlan device linked to your primary NIC and place it inside the `ns0` namesapce:

```
ip link add macvlan0 netns ns0 link eth0 type macvlan mode bridge
```

This gets us:

```
# ip -n ns0 link show macvlan0
6386: macvlan0@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c2:f9:01:dd:eb:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Assign an address to the new interface:

```
ip -n ns0 addr add 192.168.1.190/24 dev macvlan0
```

And bring up the interface:

```
ip -n ns0 link set macvlan0 up
```

---

From another system on the network:

```
pi@retropie:~ $ sudo arp-scan 192.168.1.175 192.168.1.190
Interface: wlan0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.9.5 with 2 hosts (https://github.com/royhills/arp-scan)
192.168.1.175   2c:f0:5d:c9:12:a9       (Unknown)
192.168.1.190   c2:f9:01:dd:eb:95       (Unknown)

3 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.9.5: 2 hosts scanned in 4.221 seconds (0.47 hosts/sec). 2 responded
```

I can also ping the new address:

```
pi@retropie:~ $ ping 192.168.1.190
PING 192.168.1.190 (192.168.1.190) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.190: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=25.3 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.190: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=13.5 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.190: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=10.5 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.190 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 6ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.520/16.424/25.270/6.371 ms
```

Comment: that solves the arp-scan problem but **what about ping? Does .190 respond to ping for you?**

Comment: ping works also, yes. I've added that to the answer.

Comment: Everything before ping works for me. Arp-scan works as expected, but no ping response from any machine. I have tried the solution on both Ubuntu and Debian. **Any troubleshooting ideas?**

Comment: If you're familiar with Vagrant, I've put together a complete reproducer [here](https://github.com/larsks/macvlan-example) that demonstrates the complete configuration. Note that you *cannot* ping a macvlan address **on the same host**; you will have to do that from another host on your network.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It turns out **the problem was VirtualBox**. I was able to get it to work using the above solution on **Ubuntu 22.04 using VMWare with the Bridged Adapter**.